# Why is Stack Overflow suddenly getting spammed by a bunch of random Facebookers?

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed a bunch of questions about Facebook popping up and being closed. Why are all these random people suddenly asking questions about Facebook here? Did Stack Overflow put up an advertisement and a whole bunch of angry people decided it was something to do with Facebook support?

Comment: Check out the [latest blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can more be done to stop off topic Facebook questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104157/can-more-be-done-to-stop-off-topic-facebook-questions)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first mini-site, [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com), has been launched. It's getting lots of traffic from users who don't understand what Stack Overflow is.

> ### [Announcing facebook.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)
>
> [...] So when the largest social developer platform in the world came to us and said they wanted to partner with us, we were all ears.  And because of that partnership, we are proud to announce that [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) is launching today as the new official developer support channel for all Facebook developers. [...]

> ### [Supporting Developers on Stack Overflow](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/)
>
> Today we are excited to launch [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com), a partnership with programming Q&A site Stack Overflow to support Facebook Platform developers. Many Facebook engineers actively participate on Stack Overflow, along with some of the most knowledgeable Facebook developers, making it one of the best places for you to get help with your technical questions. [...]

Comment: Let's teach them what the "close" feature is and how it works first!

Comment: Ran out of close votes 3 days in a row. Never once ran out before.

Comment: ***This facebook.SO business will get out of control. It will get out of control and we'll be lucky to live through it.***