# Why so many off-topic facebook questions lately?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Stack Overflow suddenly getting spammed by a bunch of random Facebookers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104160/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-getting-spammed-by-a-bunch-of-random-facebookers)

There seem to be many people recently who think stackoverflow is the Facebook helpdesk, and ask non-programming questions about things like [resetting passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301437/reset-password-problems) and [how to migrate friend lists from profile to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301322/how-to-get-my-5000-friends-from-my-profile-to-my-page).

Has something changed recently in SO to cause this?  Is the subdomain facebook.stackoverflow.com new and is it the cause?  Or has Facebook done something?

Comment: [Announcing facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks.  Guess that may explain this.