# What is the purpose of facebook.stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, facebook.stackoverflow

Someone post a comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050336/album-photos-rearranged) saying that a reason of having many questions about facebook could be because [http://facebook.stackoverflow exists](http://facebook.stackoverflow)

I tried to visit php.stackoverflow.com and perl.stackoverflow.com and they don't exist.

Why facebook.stackoverflow.com and no other ?
What is the main purpose of having facebook.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Every one wants to follow the leader.

Comment: The purpose is to invite bad questions from misguided users on other people's sites.

Comment: ["Announcing facebook.stackoverflow.com"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)

Comment: [Facebook Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147208/facebook-stackoverflow)

Comment: [How are new Stack Overflow mini-sites created?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103992)

Comment: It was done to get facebook to pay stackexchange some money, not because it's useful.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. It's more than only filter tag. You see only reputation gain with the `facebook` tag.

Comment: @LucM No, it shows all rep

Comment: @CodesInChaos  From the link...  "We can now create a mini-site by selecting relevant tags (in this case, anything Facebook related) and grouping together just the content from those tags. When you visit a mini-site, you’ll see only the content from those tags."  I didn't verify the rep of Jon Skeet.

Comment: @LucM Reputation != content.

Comment: @J.Steen [Then, I don't understand](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) But you're right, content != reputation :-)

Comment: @LucM What is it you don't understand? That view is filtered per time period, which is selectable up to the right. =)

Comment: @J.Steen Why Jon Skeet is not on that page ? Check my link. it's for all time...

Comment: @LucM *That* particular page is **sorted** by (I'm assuming) most reputation earned in the tag. It doesn't exclude other users. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They launched that a couple of years ago when Stack Overflow became the [official developer support channel for all Facebook developers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).  The filtered view of Stack Overflow was designed to make it easier for Facebook application developers to see only content from relevant tags.